# Is if __name__ == '__main__' in python same as the main() in java?

Tags: java, python

I am familiar with java but new to python and I wanted to know whether this piece of code is same as the main method in java **if __name__ == '__main__'**. Do all the python class need this code to execute. what if I did not have this code in my .py file. Will it throw any error message

Comment: No, it is not the same thing, but it can help you run code only if the module is used as the main entry point. Thus it is *related*.

Comment: When does the __name__ field gets initialized and how??

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html